# What is the best way to represent routing (one place to next place to next place and so on) in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have created a solution which has a routing that provides information from one site (place) to another site and so on , the solution also provides various information which is not directly linked to the site but to the path (one to another) like shuttle days and shipping method by logistics provider.
Right now I have an entity which has properties like SourceSite , TargetSite , ShuttleDays, Shipping method etc. To know complete route I am using List of this entity.

We have created hundreds of thousands routes using it.

Somehow I don't feel this is the best way to represent the data, because these entities needs to be in order where first's TargetSite should always be next's SourceSite.

Any thoughts to design better.

Comment: Take a look at `Flow` algorithms. They use the type of structure you depict here to solve specific problems like shortest routes. You might find inspiration there. [Here a sample google implementation](https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow) off the `MinCostFlow` algorythm i have used in the past. The general idea is to use a node with properties that represent the route

Comment: You can post [real code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and ask to improve it

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you want to have a graph represented by [adjacency list](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/graph-adjacency-list)

Basically, a dictionary SourceSite -> List_of_paths_from_source_site_to_various_targets.